# Are there more polynomial time problems with complexity lower bounds?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, time-complexity, lower-bounds, polynomial-time

I'm looking for more problems in $P$ with classical time complexity lower bounds.  Some people might wonder how you could prove such a lower bound.  See below.

**Exponential Lower Bounds:**

*Claim:* If you have a problem $X$ that is $EXPTIME$-complete under polynomial reductions, then there is a constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $X$ is not solvable in $O(2^{n^{\alpha}})$ time.

*Proof Idea:* By the time hierarchy theorem, there is a problem $Y$ in $O(2^n)$ time that is not in $o(\frac{2^n}{n})$ time.  Further, there must be a polynomial reduction from $Y$ to $X$.  Therefore, there is a constant $c$ such that this reduction takes an instance of size $n$ for $Y$ to an instance of size $n^c$ for $X$.  The lower bound for $Y$ of $O(2^{n^{1-\epsilon}})$ time shifts to a lower bound for $X$ of $O(2^{n^{\frac{1-\epsilon}{c}}})$ time.

**Polynomial Lower Bounds:**

Some $EXPTIME$-complete problems have nice parameterizations into polynomial time problems.  Consider the problem $X$ from before.  Suppose we have a parameterization $k$-$X$ for $X$ such that:

- For each fixed $k$, $k$-$X$ is in polynomial time.

There are of course exceptions to this, but intuitively, as $k$ grows the $k$-$X$ problems should get harder because $X$ has an exponential time complexity lower bound.

**An Example:**

One example problem that has come up is intersection non-emptiness for tree automata.  That is, given a finite list of tree automata, does there exist a tree that simultaneously satisfies all of the automata?

This problem was shown to be $EXPTIME$-complete [here](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=78382).  Further, we can parameterize the intersection problem by the number of automata $k$.  It can be [shown](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-47666-6_33) that for fixed $k$, the intersection problem has time complexity $n^{\Theta(k)}$.

**Question:**

Are there any other $EXPTIME$-complete problems that have *natural* parameterizations into polynomial time problems with nice lower bounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one involving a 2 player pebble game. You decide if it's *natural* (:

[T. Kasai, A. Adachi, S. Iwata. Classes of pebble games and complete problems. 1979](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0208046)

Theorem 3.1 has the EXPTIME-completeness of pebbling. Theorem 3.3 has the easiness of k-pebble.

[A. Adachi, S. Iwata, T. Kasai. Some Combinatorial Game Problems Require Omega(n^k) Time. 1984](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322433)

Theorem 3.2 has the lower bound on k-pebble. Lastly, you might also be interested in:

[T. Kasai and S. Iwata. Gradually intractable problems and nondeterminitstic log-space lower bounds. 1985](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01699467)

Sadly that these are all behind paywalls :(

Comment: This is wonderful!  Thank you very much.  :)